Reconstructing local Lie group multiplication from Lie algebras without using the BCH formula
A classic result in Lie groups and Lie algebras is that local Lie groups correspond to Lie algebras (this result can be found here). Specifically, the Lie bracket alone can locally recover the group multiplication, which I find quite remarkable. After all, the Lie bracket is just a linear approximation of non-commutativity. In the textbooks I've come across, this is typically explained using the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula:
$$ \exp(X) \exp(Y) = \exp\left(X + Y + \frac{1}{2}[X, Y] + \dots \right) $$
While I think the BCH formula is beautiful, I feel it is a bit too technical. In other words, if I hadn't seen the proof, I wouldn't have expected such a result to exist. I don't believe the statement "the Lie bracket can locally recover the group multiplication" is immediately obvious.
In particular, I understand that Lie himself, in his work on continuous transformation groups, already arrived at the conclusion that "local Lie groups and Lie algebras correspond" quite early on. However, in Lie's time, the BCH formula may not have existed yet. Is it possible that Lie found a way to bypass the BCH formula and instead use another method to reconstruct the local structure of a Lie group from its Lie algebra?
To explore this, I turned to Lie's Theory of Transformation Groups, hoping to find such a method. However, I found the book quite difficult to read. It uses terminology that feels quite different from modern Lie group concepts, and I struggle to connect them with contemporary ideas. Additionally, I can't find much discussion about Lie's book online. One thing I'm reasonably sure of is that the BCH formula is not used in Lie's work. In Chapter 9, Theorem 23, the book proves that "the local structure of a Lie group can be recovered from its Lie algebra," and it seems the proof involves Frobenius' theorem.
Intuitively, I lean towards believing that it's possible to bypass the BCH formula and instead use Frobenius' theorem to recover the Lie group structure. I've seen a similar example in Lie's second fundamental theorem (the statement can be found here). In Brian C. Hall's book, the proof uses the BCH formula, but a USTC lecture note presents a proof that bypasses BCH in favor of using Frobenius' theorem. However, as I mentioned earlier, I'm not sure if Lie actually used this approach, and I'm unsure how to express his proof more clearly using modern language.
My Question
So, my question is:
Did Lie indeed find a way to "recover the group multiplication locally from the Lie algebra" using Frobenius' theorem, without relying on the BCH formula? Can this method be explained intuitively, or restated more clearly using modern language? Are there any other textbooks that discuss this method?
I apologize if my language isn't completely clear, but I think many people might have encountered the same issue: the fact that the Lie bracket alone can locally recover the group multiplication is quite remarkable. Besides the BCH formula, are there alternative proofs? What was the thought process of the person who first discovered this phenomenon? I believe answering this question will help us better understand the correspondence between Lie groups and Lie algebras.

I find the question interesting, but I'm a little confused by the motivation—if you think that local Lie groups correspond to Lie algebras, then you already believe that the group multiplication can be recovered from the Lie bracket, because that's all that the Lie algebra knows!  The particularly pleasant form of BCH (or BCDH, or … one of those names, like the Weil representation, that just accretes more initials the more history you survey) may be a surprise, but the existence of a formula for the multiplication in terms of the bracket has surely already been conceded.

@LSpice My idea is as follows: If $G$ and $H$ are locally isomorphic Lie groups, then $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ must be isomorphic as vector spaces. However, if $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ are isomorphic as vector spaces, it does not necessarily follow that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic as local Lie groups. This suggests that additional structure is needed on the tangent space. Specifically, we discover the Lie bracket operation, which makes $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ into Lie algebras. [...]

[...] But why do we stop here? Why don't we consider adding more structure? Why is it that if $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ are isomorphic as Lie algebras, then $G$ and $H$ are necessarily locally isomorphic as Lie groups? I do not see this directly from the definition of the Lie bracket. The BCH formula provides a justification, but I am looking for a more intuitive reason.

Re, OK, thanks.  That makes more sense as a question—to me, less "why does the correspondence between local Lie groups and Lie algebras take this form?", but "why is there such a correspondence at all?"  Interesting question!
